# Excel vba calculate only if 7 cells have same values

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following table, Column(Dates), Rows(Id and Names).  I am trying to add the values in each row only if there are seven consecutive values in them otherwise not.  Never done any coding in vba so I am having hard time.  Tried to write the formula and vba code but not knowing the syntax it's been very difficult.

Scan from C2 to AG2
     if C2 is > 0 and C2=D2=E2=F2=G2=H2=I2 then
     add C2+D2+E2+F2+H2+I2 store this value in AL2
Repeat the process until last filled row

Any insight into this would be greatly appreciated.  I tried extensive search on this site and on google but couldn't find anything that is close to what I am doing, I was able to learn how to get the last filled column (in my case it only goes up to AH), last filled row (in my case it only goes up to 55), for loop. but not able to put this together.

Thx,
Archer

Comment: So if C2:I2 are not equal then what? Look at D2:J2 ?  If there was a match there would it also go in AL2 ?  Stop once the first run of 7 values is found and go to next row?

Comment: Use a [WorksheetFunction object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff834434.aspx) or [Application.Evaluate method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193019.aspx) to process `=if(and(count(c2:i2)=7, average(c2:i2)=c2), sum(c2:i2), "")`.

Comment: Tim,  Our macro/function would look from C2 to last value in the row, if seven consecutive cells are found with the same value then you add that value and put it in AL2, then you go to next row and do the same and so on, the result wouldbe AL2, AL3, AL4, to the end then I can use that column to do further calculations.  Thx

Comment: Jeeped, Thanks for your reply.  Your formula only works for the first cells, C2:I2, In the spreadsheet, the data could be in any cells from C to AG (one month, days) and our formula needs to go through each cell and see if there are values in 7 cells together then add them up, look for the next cell in that row, if nothing until AG  then go to C3 and continue, until the end.  I hope this make is little clear.  (I am not able to paste the picture in here)  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

A VBA user-defined-function

**EDIT**: updated to ignore blanks

```
Function GetRun(rng, num)
    Dim d, i As Long, c As Long, v, rv, tmp

    d = rng.Value
    v = Chr(0)
    rv = ""
    For c = 1 To UBound(d, 2) - 1
        tmp = d(1, c)
        'EDIT: skip blanks
        If tmp <> v Or Len(tmp) = 0 Then
            v = tmp
            i = 1
        Else
            i = i + 1
            If i = num Then
                rv = v
                Exit For
            End If
        End If
    Next c
    GetRun = rv
End Function
```

Use:

```
=GetRun(C2:AG2, 7)
```

Comment: Tim, This function is excellent, although when I copy the function all the way down to row 50, it is not calculating for other rows..sorry it took me a while, while I try to understand your code and modify it.  Sorry I couldn't fix it.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Works fine for me: see shared example at https://www.dropbox.com/s/t44rhnke1ak1jot/tmpRun.xlsm?dl=0

Comment: Tim, I see your data set works, but mine is not, I tried different things but still wouldn't  So I sharing my file here, https://www.dropbox.com/s/qocwnc0s90pea82/tmpRun.xlsm?dl=0